Adjective separated from its noun
... und entziehen dem Körper viele für sein Wohlbefinden wichtige Nährstoffe.
I had to read this phrase so many times to understand its meaning. Why is "viele" separated from "wichtige Nährstoffe"?

"s" separated from its "it" by an apostrophe ;)

Viele isn't an adjective but an indefinite pronoun. It's in the same camp as articles and other pronouns. It's at that position because it parentheses that item für sein Wohlbefinden as part of the noun phrase. Compare:

… und entziehen dem Körper für sein Wohlbefinden viele wichtige Nährstoffe.

With this word order für sein Wohlbefinden is a free floating adverbial. Those belong to the verb phrase of the clause. So they entziehen für sein Wohlbefinden. That für sein Wohlbefinden gives a reason why they entziehen.

… und entziehen dem Körper viele für sein Wohlbefinden wichtige Nährstoffe.

With this word order on the other hand für sein Wohlbefinden is part of the noun phrase viele für sein Wohlbefinden wichtige Nährstoffe and für sein Wohlbefinden gives a reason why the Nährstoffe are wichtig.
You can find this kind of parenthesis very often in German. It's one of the core principles of German word order. Things framed are bound to their frame. And those frames may also be stacked, so take care.

Seems like I completely misunderstood the sentence then. It makes sense now why the word order is as it is. Btw, what do you mean by "Things framed are bound to their frame."?

I mean that this adverbial für sein Wohlbefinden isn't free floating any more but part of that noun phrase and you can't move it outside of the noun phrase without changing the meaning. On the other hand, you can use that noun phrase as a whole in place of a noun. E.g. Viele für sein Wohlbefinden wichtige Nährstoffe werden dem Körper entzogen. It's the subject in that passive sentence.

If you compare the English translation, you can see what is going on

nutrients that are important for its wellbeing
für sein Wohlbefinden wichtige Nährstoffe

The phrase "für sein Wohlbefinden" depends on "wichtig / important" - important for what? The whole unit is a big adjectival group. German and English differ in two points here: (1) in German the complement of an adjective precedes the adjective, while in English it follows. (2) a complex adjectival group can be put in front of the noun in German but not in English:

OK: many important nutrients
?? many important for its wellbeing nutrients

So what you have is:

viele [für sein Wohlbefinden wichtige] Nährstoffe.


As a side note, it is entirely possible to follow the English word order when translating back to German: "Sie entziehen dem Körper viele Nährstoffe, die wichtig sind für sein Wohlbefinden." It's (much) less elegant and may actually betray its English origin (my American spouse finds it easier to read German books that are translations from an English original!). Mark Twain famously ranted about the German parenthization.

In addition to @Jankas answer and because of your comment, here is the complete parsing of the phrase:

und entziehen dem Körper viele für sein Wohlbefinden wichtige Nährstoffe.

The basic relationship is verb-object:

... entziehen (dem Körper) - Nährstoffe

So they (who or what "they" is is part of the rest of the sentence, but "they" must be something in Plural, because "entziehen" is in plural too and must match) take away nutritionals from the body. In a next step this is made more precise:

... entziehen dem Körper viele Nährstoffe

So they don't just "take away nutritionals" but take away many nutritionals. Now, they do not just take away many of any nutritionals, just the ones of a certain sort of them:

... entziehen dem Körper viele für sein Wohlbefinden wichtige Nährstoffe

They take away many of the nutritionals necessary for its (the bodies) wellbeing. Here is one of the major differences between English and German word order: such extended phrases are put regularily after the noun in English but before the noun (like adjectives, in which place they are) in German:
Simple adjectives:

the red car
das rote Auto

vs. phrases:

das an dem Unfall beteiligte Auto
the car involved in the crash

